# Mysql issue update command in before update trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Looking for assistance crafting a mysql trigger. My current code does not work as intended. What I would like to do is if field A in table A is modified, copy field A to field B in table A.

Current code looks like this:

```
BEGIN
IF new.set_id=301 THEN
UPDATE lighting_io_settings SET slider1_val=new.val WHERE set_id=402;
END IF;   
END
```

Obviously it fails because an update is calling an update.

Comment: Did you mean column where you say "field"?

Answer (score 1):

On **before** update you can check the old tuple value on variable "**OLD**" and check the new tuple values on "**NEW**" variable.

```
BEGIN
IF NEW.columnA != OLD.columnA THEN
   //do whatever you want here like
   NEW.columnB = NEW.columnA;
   //can call update again, just don't change the columnA
   update tableA set columnB = NEW.columnA where id = 402;
END IF;   
END
```